# Will .net Core 3 running on a Windows 10 IOT work with WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core

I've read a lot about the new upcoming .NET Core 3, which states that it now support building WinForms and WPF application. But, I haven't been able to figure out if this will also be supported on a device like the Raspberry PI running Windows 10 IOT. It clearly states that this will be a Windows only feature, but 
does that really includes the IOT version of Windows too, which of cause is an ARM system.

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of win 10 iot.
The core version is a no.
The enterprise version has a full windows shell and is a yes.

More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot

Comment: If that's true, why would it be such a great news that .net Core now has UI, if it only works on systems which already support it with the full framework?

Comment: No, WPF is intimately tied to DirectX, the only way it could be made to work on non-Windows machines would be if milcore was re-written to use OpenGL instead. And as anyone who remembers the 3D API wars of the late 90s will tell you, the chance of that happening is approximately 0% due to the political fire-storm that would inevitably ensue as a result.

Comment: But why does .net core 3 support UI then.. it makes no sense as you would always only use it on systems where the full .net framework exists anyway.

Comment: You realise .Net core runs faster?  In porting the code they've taken the opportunity to improve, fix and optimise the framework code.

Comment: Yes i did know that. But that's not what they sell .net Core 3 by. Only the .net Core project itself of cause.  So the UI part of .net Core 3 is not big news, other than it's just faster.. it brings nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

WPF on .NET Core will be delivered in a "desktop pack" that only works on desktop versions on Windows. Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/12/15/wpf-on-net-core/) blog post for more information about the new stuff regarding the SDK.

> If that's true, why would it be such a great news that .net Core now has UI, if it only works on systems which already support it with the full framework?

1. You will be able to take advantage of the various performance improvements that have been introduced in .NET Core
2. You will be able to deploy WPF applications as self-contained executables (.exes) that have no dependency upon any pre-installed version of .NET
3. You will get support for the .NET Core CLI tools and SDK-style projects in Visual Studio